Why does $\hat{\beta}_0$ not converge almost surely in my LAD model?
I am running simulations to explore the convergence properties of $\hat{\beta}_0$ (the median) in a least absolute deviation (LAD) model. Specifically, I estimate $\beta_0$ from a simple location model $y_i = \beta_0 + e_i$, where $e_i$ represents i.i.d. noise.
Simulation Setup
True parameter: $\beta_0 = 2$.
Sample sizes: $T = 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, \dots, 50000$.
Noise types:

Gaussian: $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$,
Laplace: $\text{scale} = 1$,
Cauchy: $\text{location} = 0, \text{scale} = 1$.

For reproducibility, I used fixed noise trajectories (i.e., the same noise sample for all repetitions at a given $T$).
I computed $\hat{\beta}_0$ as the median of $y_i$ and repeated the process $N = 1000$ times for each configuration. I then evaluated the mean absolute error (MAE):
$$\text{MAE} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N |\hat{\beta}_0^{(i)} - \beta_0|.$$
The following figure summarizes the MAE for each noise type across $T$:

Question:
Why does $\hat{\beta}_0$ fail to converge almost surely to $\beta_0$ in this setting? Could this be due to the properties of the noise distributions (e.g., heavy tails for Cauchy) or the characteristics of the LAD estimator? Is there relevant literature that addresses this issue?
Thank you in advance for your insights!

I am not sure how to infer a.s. convergence from a simulation, but there does seem to be convergence for large $T$, no? Given the outliers from a Cauchy, persistent deviations from true values seem possible, however. Have you checked https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373526/consistent-unbiased-estimator-for-the-location-parameter-of-mathcalcauchy, which suggests at least convergence in probability?
